# MySQL Workbench Import CSV Character Decoding/Encoding Error

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, mysql-workbench, non-ascii-characters

I was trying to import a csv file into a MySQL table, using MySQL Workbench. However, I kept getting this character decoding error:
[Unhandled exception: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 418: character maps to <undefined>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt74t.png)

So then I used the following MySQL command to directly load the file into the database:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE [file path]
INTO TABLE mock_word
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(Source, Word_ID, OriginalWord, OriginalTranslation, LabWordCategory);
```

This executed without any errors, but when I then tried to export the table as a csv file using MySQL Workbench, I get a character encoding error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x81' in position 35: character maps to <undefined>
ERROR: Export data to file: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x81' in position 35: character maps to <undefined>
Failed
```

The MySQL table's Charset/Collation is `utf8mb4`/`utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. The csv file contains phonetic symbols, which I think might be what's causing problems.

How might I deal with this issue? Thank you!

Below I've copy+pasted the entirety of the csv file (here's a link to the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y8JQc1x1t0erUwsVrv193CjI8FISFlkv/view?usp=sharing). Word_ID is what I'm using as the primary key.

```
Source,Word_ID,OriginalWord,OriginalTranslation,LabWordCategory
ASG1848,word:ASG1848:002,ahkeya,woman,N
ASG1848,word:ASG1848:003,akuia,woman,N
ASG1848,word:ASG1848:025,owotan okitz,nails,N
AT1967,word:AT1967:078,payóónixkaasi,"when, if it gets broken",V
AT1967,word:AT1967:079,payóónixkaawa,it is broken,V
AT1969,word:AT1969:0265,ayóxkotokaaʔsiyaaʔwa,they became rocks,V
AT1969,word:AT1969:0306,iiksíkimmapiipitsiʔwa,"he is always very kind, he is a very kind person",V
AT1969,word:AT1969:0537,maanʔssíʔwa,"he is young, he is new",V
AT1969,word:AT1969:0697,nítsaayiipitsi,I lie,V
AT1969,word:AT1969:1286,amíxkaata,fish thou!,V
AT1969,word:AT1969:1465,apóónistoota,smash it!,V
AT1969,word:AT1969:2576,nitááʔsiiyàttsyaaʔwa,I made him sneeze,V
AT1969,word:AT1969:3306,áaakitsskixsiʔpyaaʔwa,we (incl) will dry them,V
CU_RVG1930,word:CU_RVG1930:00287,áikapisimiitapaumixkau,he is often fishing alone secretly,V
CU_RVG1930,word:CU_RVG1930:01190,imaχkópiu,he has a big arrow,V
CU_RVG1930,word:CU_RVG1930:02894,ksistuyíu,[it] is warm,V
CU_RVG1930,word:CU_RVG1930:03703,istókimàtsists,drums,N
CU_RVG1930,word:CU_RVG1930:03743,itåχkanáitàpixkitsìi,(the pieces of meat) all became dry,V
CU_RVG1930,word:CU_RVG1930:14905,ksistókúmiu (ksistókómiu),it is warm (of liquids) (in.),V
CU_RVG1930,word:CU_RVG1930:15445,ɑkáukakyapakeua,she is already a wise woman,V
DGF_NJR2017,word:DGF_NJR2017:0001,opóónit!,shatter it!,V
DGF_NJR2017,word:DGF_NJR2017:0002,nitsíípóónii’pa,I broke it,V
DGF_NJR2017,word:DGF_NJR2017:0003,áakopoonistoomáyi,he will smash it (by dropping or throwing it),V
GR1917,word:GR1917:0303,ákéuαm,woman,N
GR1917,word:GR1917:1074,manáke,New-woman,N
GR1917,word:GR1917:1160,mánatåχkàpinausiks,(those) that had (also) a new way of dressing,N
JT1889,word:JT1889:2456,omǔk'o,it is big,V
JT1889,word:JT1889:2457,omǔk'sim,he is big (man),V
JT1889,word:JT1889:3852,ikhitsi'u,it is dry,V
JT1889,word:JT1889:3853,ikhsǐs',dry him,V
JT1889,word:JT1889:3854,ikhsit,dry thou it,V
JT1889,word:JT1889:3856,ikhsu'yiu,he is dry,V
JT1889,word:JT1889:7011,nitǔs'sǔmmosi,I see myself,V
JT1889,word:JT1889:7331,apon'it,smash it,V
JT1889,word:JT1889:7437,epon'ǐmaie,he smashes it,V
JT1889,word:JT1889:7472,nitse'ponip,I smash it,V
JT1889,word:JT1889:8866,ksǐstusǐs',warm him,V
JT1889,word:JT1889:8867,ksǐstusit',warm it,V
JT1889,word:JT1889:8869,ksǐstusu'yit,warm yourself,V
JT1889,word:JT1889:8872,ksǐstusǔk'sǐnni,warming (a third object),N
DGF_NJR2017,word:DGF_NJR2017:0004,ksiistokómssakit!,heat water!,V
DGF_NJR2017,word:DGF_NJR2017:0005,iníkkoyihkaamisa!,scold her!,V
DGF_NJR2017,word:DGF_NJR2017:0006,pottááhkomoosa!,scare the wildfowl into flight for him!,V
```

Comment: What came before and after the hex 81?

Comment: The question marks (even in the link) may be a "substitution character" to indicate a _previous_ interpretation failed.  I see on Greek letter; that seems strange.  Any idea whether the text is in some particular language?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I miss column name. Ensure column name in the file.